# WCF service method creates a Process to run MsTest, the process will not execute

Tags: c#, wcf, process, mstest

I created a WCF method to execute MsTest command to run test, like:

```
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"cmd";
//I used Test Agent
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"mstest /testcontainer:MyTests.dll /test:MyTests.TestMethod1 /unique /resultsfile:C:\TestResults\TestMethod1.trx");
```

When I debug this method in a console project, it works well. But when I run the WCF test method, it seems nothing happened. When I debug it, I can call the WCF method and the code seems to be executed, but in fact no result.

Do you have any idea about this please?

Comment: Is there an exception being thrown ?

Comment: no, everything seems normal.

Comment: Sounds like the account which the WCF services run under has no enough privileges to run the process.
Can you try to run the WCF service with an administrator account ?

Comment: I would be taking a look at the server with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  Also, why are you going through `cmd`?  Just call `mstest` directly.

Comment: This setup seams unnecessary complex - why do you need it, what is your use case? Perhaps there is a easier way to solve your problem!

Comment: thanks a lot, mkArtak, Mitch and Jocke. This is just a demo, I need to create a service to run my own test in DLL file. mkArtak, Mitch, I will try your methods. @Jocke, chould you please tell me more about your easier way? thanks. I need it because I can not run my test in DLL directly, I didn't find a way to initialize the test context for SpecFlow based on unit test. So, I use mstest command to run test.

Comment: @Mitch, can you please show me how to call mstest directly? I give the process startinfo filename "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe", it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amended code below will correctly locate `mstest.exe` and validate the existence of input and output files.  If the expected output does not get created, we throw an exception with the error output from the process.  We only use full paths to avoid changing the working-directory.

These changes should, at least, point you in the right direction in terms of what is going wrong when using it from WCF.

Note, however, that the code below suffers from multiple bugs which could affect security if this is accepting input from untrusted clients.  Caveat programmer.

```
// Example use
RunTest(@"..\..\..\UnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject1.dll", "UnitTest1.TestMethod2", "out2.trx");

private static void RunTest(string testDll, string testMethod, string outFile)
{
    //Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(testDll));
    //Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(testMethod));
    //Contract.Requires(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outFile));

    testDll = Path.GetFullPath(testDll);
    // this and all of the other tests suffer from TOCTOU issues, but they
    // are just advisory.  MSTest is the real gauntlet.
    if (!File.Exists(testDll))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("testDll not found", testDll);
    }

    outFile = Path.GetFullPath(outFile);
    if (File.Exists(outFile) || !Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(outFile)))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("outFile already exists or directory does not exist");
    }

    string msTestLoc = GetMsTestPath("12.0"); // 12 == 2013, 11 = 2012, 10 == 2010, 9 == 2008

    // while testDll and outFile are minimally validated, testMethod is a
    // ripe target for injection into the command arguments.  Validation
    // would be appropriate.
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(msTestLoc, string.Format(
        "/testcontainer:\"{0}\" /test:{1} /unique /resultsfile:\"{2}\"",
        testDll, testMethod, outFile))
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };
    var proc = Process.Start(psi);

    var errorOutput = new StringBuilder();
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += (_1, args) => errorOutput.AppendLine(args.Data);
    proc.OutputDataReceived += (_1, args) => errorOutput.AppendLine(args.Data);
    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

    proc.WaitForExit();
    // we would check the return code here, but they don't seem to be documented
    if (!File.Exists(outFile))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("mstest.exe did not produce an "
            + "output file:\r\n" + errorOutput.ToString());
    }
}

private static string GetMsTestPath(string vsVersion)
{
    //Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<string>() != null);
    //Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vsVersion));

    using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32))
    using (var vsReg = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\" + vsVersion))
    {
        var res = (string)vsReg.GetValue("InstallDir");
        if (res == null || !Directory.Exists(res))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("VS install path not found");
        }

        var msbuildPath = Path.Combine(res, "mstest.exe");
        if (!File.Exists(msbuildPath))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("MSTest not found");
        }

        return msbuildPath;
    }
}
```